# IBM Watson SpeechToTextをUnity上で利用したいです

Tags: c#, unity3d, watson-api

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/jp/cloud/library/unity/index.html
を参考にWatsonのSpeechToTextをUnity上で利用しようとしております。

watsonをアセット下に配置した際のエラーは該当箇所をコメントアウトしました。
もともとのコード（SampleSpeechToText.cs）を実行しようとするとエラーが発生してしまうため
Audioclip _clipRecord=null;
に変え、またHandleOnRecognize(SpeechRecognitionEvent result)内にも
resultがnullでないか出力させています。

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Services.SpeechToText.v1;

public class SampleSpeechToText : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]
    //private AudioClip m_AudioClip = new AudioClip();
    AudioClip _clipRecord = null;
    private SpeechToText m_SpeechToText = new SpeechToText();


    // Use this for initialization
    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        // 音声をマイクから 3 秒間取得する
        Debug.Log("Start record"); //集音開始
        var audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        audioSource.clip = Microphone.Start(null, true, 10, 44100);
        audioSource.loop = false;
        audioSource.spatialBlend = 0.0f;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
        Microphone.End(null); //集音終了
        Debug.Log("Finish record");

        // ためしに録音内容を再生してみる
        audioSource.Play();

        // SpeechToText を日本語指定して、録音音声をテキストに変換
        m_SpeechToText.RecognizeModel = "ja-JP_BroadbandModel";
        //m_SpeechToText.RecognizeModel = "en-US_BroadbandModel";
        m_SpeechToText.Recognize(audioSource.clip, HandleOnRecognize);
    }

    void HandleOnRecognize(SpeechRecognitionEvent result)
    {
        Debug.Log(result);
        if (result != null && result.results.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (var res in result.results)
            {
                foreach (var alt in res.alternatives)
                {
                    string text = alt.transcript;
                    Debug.Log(string.Format("{0} ({1}, {2:0.00})\n", text, res.final ? "Final" : "Interim", alt.confidence));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

実行すると、再生されるのですがresultはnullで返され、テキストに変換されません。
環境はwindows,
unity:2018.4.13f1です。

お手数をおかけいたしますが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: こちらでアップデートされている(それでも1年半以上前ですが)ようですが、参考になるかも。[developerWorks記事「Watson×Unity！初心者でもできる、VR 空間で Unity ちゃんとおしゃべりアプリ！」を試してみる](https://qiita.com/yamachan360/items/911204e57957bd4bbef0), [続、developerWorks記事「Watson×Unity！初心者でもできる、VR 空間で Unity ちゃんとおしゃべりアプリ！」を試してみる](https://qiita.com/yamachan360/items/bcfa10b2d9bf62df8300)

Comment: ありがとうございます。試してみたのですが、参加資格情報が記事のものと現在のものが異なっていたり、RESTConnector中にErrorが存在しない等のエラーが表示され、記事のようには動作いたしませんでした。